# PHP- Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, get

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en mysql en php, pero me da error en la linea 131, que es:

```
$num = $res->num_rows;
```

El error es:

> Trying to get property of non-object.

Se que el error viene de la consulta pero no lo encuentro ¿Podríais ayudarme por favor?

Este es el código:

```
function Enlazar($conexion,$NumAlbaran,$cont,$empCont,$fecha2){
    $conseguido = true;
    //buscamos su entrega
    //mala sentencia sql
    $ocup = 'ocupado';
    $ent = 'Entrega';
    $res = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT albaran.NumAlbaran,albaran.fecha,albaran.fecha_pagado FROM albaran,contenedor,solicita   WHERE contenedor.estado = '".$ocup."' and  numCont = '".$cont."' and solicita.empresa = '".$empCont."' and albaran.tipo='".$ent."'  ");
    $num = $res->num_rows;
    echo $num;
    if($num == 1 ){
        $a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        $intervalo = CalcularIntervalo2($a_res['fecha'],$a_res['fecha_pagado'],$fecha2);
        //vinculamos la entrega con su recogida/residuo
        $aux = $a_res['NumAlbaran'];
        $res2 = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO enlace (NEntrega,NRecogida,dias) VALUES ($aux,'$NumAlbaran','$intevalo') ");

        if(!$res2){
            $conseguido = false;
        }

    }
    else{
        $conseguido = false;
    }
    return $conseguido;
}
```

Las tabla albaran tiene los campos: 
NumAlbaran,nomEmp,localizacion,fecha,tipo y fecha_pagado.

La tabla solicita, con la que enlazo los albaranes con los contenedores tiene los campos: numAlbaran,numCont,empresa.

La tabla contenedor tiene: numCont,empresa,tamaño,estado.

Comment: Seguramente la consulta ha dado un error y $res es nulo

Comment: Es lo que dice @JaviMollá salvo que devuelve FALSE en vez de nulo. http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: ¿Y sabéis por qué puede dar error?

Comment: Pues habría que ver qué error devuelve la consulta pero, de momento, veo que en el from tienes tres tablas pero no las relacionas entre ellas. Además, hay un parámetro numCont que no está asociado a ninguna de las tres tablas. Y eso sin saber cuáles son los valores que tienen las variables...

Comment: prueba a añadir al final de la instruccion de mysql-query() lo siguiente: `or die(mysqli_error($conexion));`. Esto deberia mostrarte el error de la consulta

Comment: ¡Ostras,Muchas gracias! Como había puesto antes el Natrural Join, al ver que daba error lo quité y se me olvidó asociarlas porque aún pensaba en él. ¡Muchas gracias!